# What is a symplectic form of the rotation group SO(n)

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-equations, rigid-analytic-spaces

I need to prove that the Hamiltonian system  of the rigid body motion 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{R}_t=P_tJ^{-1},\\
\dot{P}_t=2R_t\Lambda,\quad\text{$\Lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier}\\
R_t^T R_t-I=0,
\end{cases}
$$
corresponds to the Lagrangian 
$$
\begin{array}{lccl}
\mathbb{L}:&[a,b]\times SO(n)\times TSO(n)&\longrightarrow& \mathbb{R}\\
&(t,R_t,\dot{R}_t)&\longmapsto&\mathbb{L}(t,R_t,V)=\frac{1}{2}tr(\dot{R} J \dot{R}^T),
\end{array}
$$
is completely integrable system, so what is the usual symplectic form of the $SO(n)$-group?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question about whether the system is completely integrable or not, but $SO(n)$ never carries a symplectic form:  $H^2(SO(n); \mathbb{R}) = 0$ for any $n$.  More generally, for any Lie group with simple Lie algebra $H^2$ vanishes.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean.

Comment: On a compact symplectic manifold of dimension $n$, non-degeneracy of the symplectic form $\omega$ implies the exterior power $\omega^{n/2}$ is non-trivial.  This has many corollaries.  For example, as Andrea mentions, $n/2$ must be an integer so $n$ must be even.  In addition, $\omega^{n/2}$ is a volume form, so your manifold is orientable.  But one can go further.  Since $d\omega = 0$, $\omega$ represents something in the 2nd de Rham cohomology group of $M$, $H_{\text{de Rham}}^2(M)$.  Because $\omega^{n/2}$ is non-trivial, this thing it represents is nonzero, so, in particular, $H^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: The next claim I am making is that for any simple Lie group (like $SO(n)$ for $n=3$ or $n\geq 5$), that $H^2 = 0$.  (And, in fact, $H^2(SO(4)) = H^2(SO(2)) = 0$ also).  Thus, by my previous comment, no simple Lie group or $SO(n)$ has any symplectic form at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good  answer, but can you give me the standard $H^2(SO(n))$ because what I need is to prove that this system has sufficiently many first integral with respect to $H^2$.

Comment: We may be using $H^2$ in conflicting senses.  For me, $H^2  =H^2_{\text{de Rham}}(M)$ is the group obtained as follows.  Let $\Omega^k(M)$ denote the vector space of all differential $k$-forms on $M$.  Then the differential $d$ maps $\Omega^k$ to $\Omega^{k+1}$.  Then, by definition, $H^2$ is the quotient group $\frac{\operatorname{ker} d:\Omega^2\rightarrow \Omega 3}{\operatorname{Im} d:\Omega^1\rightarrow \Omega 2}.$

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, I would deduce from the domain of definition of your Lagrangean that $SO(n)$ is the configuration space of your system and not the phase space. The phase space should be the cotangent bundle $T^*SO(n)$ and then the symplectic form is the standard form which is available on any cotangent bundle. (As noted in the comment of @JasonDeVito, $SO(n)$ itself does not carry a natural symplectic form, it may even have odd dimension ...)

Comment: You mean $H^2=tr(dR\wedge JdP)$?

Comment: What I mean is that in appropriate coordinates the symplectic form is $\sum dq^ii\wedge dp_i$.  (Here the $q^i$ are coordinates on $SO(n)$ and the $p_i$ are the induced fiber coordinates on $T^*SO(n)$.